# Создание и заполнение массива массивами PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Как создать заполнить массив массивами примерно так у меня есть цифра 150
я должен создать массив типа

```
массив = 
(
0 => массив(
0 => 1, 
1 => 2, 
2 => 3, 
3 => 4, 
4 => 5), 
1 => массив( и так далее по 5 на каждый массив))
```

просто получается надо взять цифру 150 и разбить ее на цифры по 5 в массивы внутри массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В одну строку:

```
var_export( array_chunk(range(1, 150), 5) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
$count = 1;
for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
    for($f=0;$f<5;$f++){
        $arr[$i][$f] = $count;
        $count++;
    }
}
```